# Terminate a set on EC2 instances by tags using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Faily new to AWS however I am looking to terminate a set of ec2 instances using the AWS CLI by filtering by a Tag name.

If I use `describe-instances`, I can `filter` by tag:key=*value* . For `terminate-instances` I don't see a way of filtering. I assume this is possible since I can filter and terminate using the AWS console but I am looking to do this via CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `terminate-instances` command only takes a list of instance IDs. You would need to write a script to run the `describe-instances` command first and capture the instance IDs, then pass those IDs to the `terminate-instances` command.

Comment: Ah, got it. I can run something like `aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=MYTAG" --output text` to get the list then run the terminate-instances on each one.

Comment: I've found jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) indispensable for this kind of stuff. You could do something like `INSTANCE_IDS=`aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=MYTAG" | jq .[][][]`` and then use $INSTANCE_IDS in the `aws e2 terminate-instances` command. (I can't figure out how to format the comment correctly - there should backticks around the aws command piped to the jq command with the result assigned to the variable)

Comment: Oops, tested the above... Use -r on the jq command to remove the quotes around the instanceid values.

Comment: // , Michael, you could add an answer

Answer (score 20):

Latest AWS CLI allows you to avoid the need for any scripts or jq:

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --filters "Name=tag:tagkey,Values=tagvalue" --output text)
```

as long as the number of expected instances is not huge, the above can be used.

Comment: To ensure that it's not huge, filter for only running instances  `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --filters "Name=tag:tagkey,Values=tagvalue" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --output text)

Answer (score 1):

I created the following script(.sh) and it worked for me:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters 'Name=tag-value,Values=MYTAG' --output text |
grep stopped |
awk '{print $2}' |
while read line;
do aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $line
done
```

Comment: // , Had to modify it to the following to get it to work from CEntOS 7.5 with `aws-cli/1.14.28 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.8.35`: https://gist.github.com/v6/9daa7c7027700f4cd855befac0e1dd50