# How to get not tagged instance in AWS in Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I want to get instances which are not tagged by some specific key but unable to get desired output below is my code

```
import boto3
import json
import time
import os

client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instances(
#    DryRun=True|False,
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag: elasticbeanstalk:environment-name',
            'Values': [
                'Not tagged'
            ]
        }
    ]
)
print(response)
```

output I am getting

```
{u'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'b66a2bb5-ac75-4bc1-b359-fdac50fdfaee', 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 21 Mar 2017 12:55:12 GMT'}}}
```

reference: [boto3 reference](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the underlying API does not support this kind of filtering. The only way to find it would be to query for everything, or a subset of machines in a particular state such as *RUNNING*, then do the filtering for untagged resources in python.

See this related question: [Finding all Amazon AWS Instances That Do Not Have a Certain Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858120/finding-all-amazon-aws-instances-that-do-not-have-a-certain-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following before to get InstanceIds of EC2 which is not tagged, you could modify the code a bit to get the desired output.

Hope it helps:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
        region_name='eu-west-1',
        profile_name='myprofile'
        )

ec2 = session.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_instances()

obj_number = len(response['Reservations'])

for objects in xrange(obj_number):
    try:
        z = response['Reservations'][objects]['Instances'][0]['Tags'][0]['Key']
    except KeyError as e:
        untagged_instanceid = response['Reservations'][objects]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
        untagged_state = response['Reservations'][objects]['Instances'][0]['State']['Name']
        print("InstanceID: {0}, RunningState: {1}".format(untagged_instanceid, untagged_state))
```

The output for the above code, will look like the following:

```
$ python get_untagged_ec2.py
InstanceID: i-012345abcdefg, RunningState: running
InstanceID: i-123456hijklmn, RunningState: running
InstanceID: i-234567opqrstu, RunningState: running
```