# How to filter not equal to in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I am trying to find all non-window images:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --region us-east-2 --image-ids ami-** --filters "Name=platform, Values=windows"
```

Above gives me all windows platform id's. Is there a way to do not inside this cli? I tried Values!=, <>. Search through stackoverflow but did not find anything.

Comment: Do you only wish to find your _own_ images, or all publicly accessible images? If it is just your own, you will want to include `owner=self`, otherwise you will get hundreds of images returned.

Comment: aws cli doesn't have the inverse filtering and so you need to use other functions. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858120/finding-all-amazon-aws-instances-that-do-not-have-a-certain-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Python3 code will list all of your own account's AMIs that are *not* Windows:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')

images = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])

for image in images['Images']:
    if 'Platform' not in image:
        print(image['ImageId'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a query on the cli command like this

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-** --region us-east-2 --query 'Images[?Platform != `windows`]'
```