# Filtering the EC2 instances based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, command-line-interface, jq

I am trying to filter the instances that doesnot have the required tag in place. For example I have bunch of EC2 with **Key : app and Value: prod**. What I am trying to do is that it should loop through the instances and list the instances that do not have the expected key and value. It should verify both key and value. Also it would be great if it do based on case sensitive stuff.

```
{
            "Key": "app",
            "ResourceType": "instance",
            "Value": "prod"
  }
```

if the instances have tag with above format it should list out. In case if it dont have the tag with **key : app and value : prod** or if it have Tag with case sensitive like below

```
{
                "Key": "App",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "Prod"
}
```

or Value with different value

```
{
                "Key": "app",
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Value": "production"
 }
```

It should filter.

currently I tried with below command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:environment,Values=deveu" | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "app"}, {Value: "prod"}]}) | not).Tags | .[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value'
```

But it doesnot look for value field. It only cosider the key,if it sees **app** it skips.

**Expected output**
should list the instances not with tags **key : app and value : prod** . If we could filter with case sensitive it would be even great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a wonderful list of examples on this topic, see: [Finding all Amazon AWS Instances That Do Not Have a Certain Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18858120/174777)

That page aims to find instances that **do not have a specific tag Key**, but doesn't directly answer your question of finding instances without a Key + Value combination.

Taking the examples from that page, I managed to create this query that shows the InstanceId of any instance that does not have `Key=app` and `Value=prod`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `app` && Value == `prod`].Value)] | [].InstanceId'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "list out" and "filter". Given the following made-up input:

```json
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "Key": "app",
          "ResourceType": "instance1",
          "Value": "prod"
        },
        {
          "Key": "App",
          "ResourceType": "instance2",
          "Value": "Prod"
        },
        {
          "Key": "app",
          "ResourceType": "instance3",
          "Value": "production"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This will select (=keep) the items where both fields are unequal to their respective values (using `and` and `!=`):

```bash
.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Key != "app" and .Value != "prod")
```

```json
{
  "Key": "App",
  "ResourceType": "instance2",
  "Value": "Prod"
}
```

This will select (=keep) the items where at least one of the fields is unequal to its respective value (using `or` and `!=`):

```bash
.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Key != "app" or .Value != "prod")
```

```json
{
  "Key": "App",
  "ResourceType": "instance2",
  "Value": "Prod"
}
{
  "Key": "app",
  "ResourceType": "instance3",
  "Value": "production"
}
```

This will select (=keep) the items where both fields are equal to their respective values (using `and` and `==`):

```bash
.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Key == "app" and .Value == "prod")
```

```json
{
  "Key": "app",
  "ResourceType": "instance1",
  "Value": "prod"
}
```